# How do I load an item from API to a fragment inside an Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to load elements from my API to a fragment inside an activity, but once I initialize the element inside of the Activity Class present in the fragment like the TextView the app crashes.

[This is what the property Profile Activity looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJolj.png)

this is the PropertyProfile Kotlin Code

```
val item = intent.getSerializableExtra("item") as DemoDataBaseItem
    val url = intent.getStringExtra("url")

    aboutp = findViewById(R.id.frag_details_text)
    locationp = findViewById(R.id.profile_location)
    profilenametext = findViewById(R.id.profile_property_name)
    profileratingbar = findViewById(R.id.profile_rating_bar)
    profileimageview = findViewById(R.id.imv_property_profile)
    bnow_button = findViewById(R.id.booknow_btn)
    call = findViewById(R.id.call_btn)

    aboutp.text = item.about_property
    locationp.text = item.location_country
    profilenametext.text = item.property_name
    profileratingbar.rating = item.rating_bar.toFloat()
    Glide.with(this).load(item.imageurl).centerCrop()
        .into(profileimageview)

    call.setOnClickListener {
        //open the call intent
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", item.property_phone, null))
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    bnow_button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, Webview::class.java)
        val finalURL = "${item.beurl}#checkin=${checkinText.text}&checkout=${checkoutText.text}"
        intent.putExtra("item", item)
        intent.putExtra("url", finalURL)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

this is the code in the Main Activity

```
    fun getAllData(){
        Api.retrofitService.getAllData().enqueue(object: Callback<List<DemoDataBaseItem>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<DemoDataBaseItem>>,
                response: Response<List<DemoDataBaseItem>>
            ) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    datalist = response.body()!!.toMutableList()
                    mAdapter = MyAdapter(response.body()!!, this@MainActivity)
                    recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

                }


            }


            //required DO NOT REMOVE, this is for error tracking
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<DemoDataBaseItem>>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })

    }


        //additional url adding
        override fun onClick(item: DemoDataBaseItem) {
        val intent = Intent(this, PropertyProfile::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("item", item)
        startActivity(intent)
    }






}





interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(item: DemoDataBaseItem)

}
```

The code for the Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.cloudbeds.dummyapitest1.R



class Details : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)


    }
}
```

I need to load the "about_property" item in the API to the textview in the fragment

Comment: Can you please provide the exception stacktrace, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have the Exception stack trace, I would recommend you to pass it in a Bundle, because I would say the Exception occurs when this casting happens:

```
val item = intent.getSerializableExtra("item") as DemoDataBaseItem
```

try to send the data with a bundle as the following:

```
val intent = Intent(this, FontAwesomeChip::class.java).apply {
            putExtras(
                bundleOf(
                    "item" to $YOUR_ITEM,
                    "url" to $YOUR_URL
                )
            )
        }
        startActivity(intent)
```

To get the data in the Activity you want, use the onNewIntent Activity method as the following:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (intent?.hasExtra("item") == true && intent.hasExtra("url")) {
            val item = intent.getSerializableExtra("item") as $YOUR_CLASS_TYPE
            val url = intent.getStringExtra("url")
            //textView.text = item.property for example
        } 
    }
```

I think I'm not forgetting nothing, should work :D